# How can I fetch data synchronously from cordova-sqlite?

Tags: jquery, sql, sqlite, cordova

### Is it possible to fetch data synchronously from cordova-sqlite?

I have a table `caseTable` with fields (ID, caseName, date). Each row in that table corresponds to another table named after the caseName field. I need to loop through the `caseTable` table and get a count of the number of rows in the table referred to.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("Casepad", "1.0", "Casepad", 200000);
    db.transaction(getallTableData, errorCB);    
}

function insertData() {
    db.transaction(createTable, errorCB, afterSuccessTableCreation);
}

// create table and insert some record
function createTable(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName  TEXT unique NOT NULL ,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea TEXT NOT NULL)');

    tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("' + $('.caseName_h').val() + '", "' + $('.caseDate_h').val() + '","' + $('.caseTextArea_h').val() + '")');


}
// function will be called when an error occurred
function errorCB(err) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}

// function will be called when process succeed
function afterSuccessTableCreation() {
    console.log("success!");
    db.transaction(getallTableData, errorCB);
}


// select all from SoccerPlayer
function getallTableData(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}


function querySuccess(tx, result) {
    var len = result.rows.length;
    var t;
    $('#folderData').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        /* *************************************************************
         * Here i need to call a synchronous method which returns the
         * number of rows in the result.rows.item(i).CaseName table 
         * ************************************************************* */
        $('#folderData').append(
                '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + result.rows.item(i).id + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseName + t+'</h2>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).TextArea + '</p>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseDate + '</p>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span></a>' + 
                 '<span class="ctrl togg"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" ><button class="edit button_design">Edit</button><button class="del button_design">Delete</button></fieldset><span>'+'</li>'
                );
    }
    $('#folderData').listview('refresh');

}
```

Instend of showing value of "i" in list view i need to show how many element in that table . I need to call synchronise because i need to call some query which count the number of element in "result.rows.item(i).CaseName" in this element..?

Take Example ...

DB Name **Case Pad**
Table Name CaseTable

```
    Let assume having entries in caseTable.


      ID      CaseName      Case Date   caseNote
        1         Test           3/77/13   jgjgj
        2         Test2          4/34/3   hsadkkadsh 


Now I have two more table in DB
Test , Test2..

    **Test** having entries like this

       ID          DocumentName    Date         Notes
       1)           ppp              7/33         asdhdfkdshf
       2)           asdjhad            9/44       dfjasgfsjfj
    **Test2** having entries like this

       ID          DocumentName    Date         Notes
       1)           sad            7/4         asdhdfkdshf
       2)           assd           3/44          hhhhhh
       3)            asd           2/22          adgjad
```

Now Test , Test2 have entry is 2 and 3.

Now i need to fetch data of CaseTable .While fetch i need to count Number of element in my casename table (Test, Test1). here only

```
 function getallTableData(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }



    function querySuccess(tx, result) {
        var len = result.rows.length;
        var t;
        $('#folderData').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Here i need to call synchronize method which call the number of element in in that  result.rows.item(i).CaseName and insert it in this table
    ****************************************************************************
            $('#folderData').append(
                    '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + result.rows.item(i).id + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseName + t+'</h2>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).TextArea + '</p>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseDate + '</p>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span></a>' + 
                     '<span class="ctrl togg"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" ><button class="edit button_design">Edit</button><button class="del button_design">Delete</button></fieldset><span>'+'</li>'
                    );
        }
        $('#folderData').listview('refresh');

    }
```

**I need to Print casename casedate case Note ,number of elements**
So my list is look like this

```
 Test           3/77/13   jgjgj      2
 Test2          4/34/3   hsadkkadsh  3
```

How to print 2 and 3 in that table...:( can you please give me any query)

Comment: What exactly is the SQL query you need to run synchronously?

Comment: i will explain . that i need to count number of elements in table while iteration.As i told you i have table casetable(ID , casename) while inserting any value i also create another table of casename. I insert some value in that.i need to count number of elements in case name tables while fetching data of caseTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through them asynchronously by doing something like this (not tested, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
var count = 0;
var caseTableResult = [];

var getallTableData = function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

var querySuccess = function (tx, result) {
    if (count === 0) {
        caseTableResult = result;
        $('#folderData').empty();
    } else {
        var i = count - 1;
        $('#folderData').append(
                '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + caseTableResult.rows.item(i).id + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>' + caseTableResult.rows.item(i).CaseName + t+'</h2>' + '<p>' + caseTableResult.rows.item(i).TextArea + '</p>' + '<p>' + caseTableResult.rows.item(i).CaseDate + '</p>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span></a>' + 
                 '<span class="ctrl togg"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" ><button class="edit button_design">Edit</button><button class="del button_design">Delete</button></fieldset><span>'+'</li>'
        );
    }

    if (count <= caseTableResult.rows.length) {
        // Call the next query
        count += 1;
        tx.executeSql('SELECT count(*) FROM ' + caseTableResult.rows.item(i).CaseName, [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    } else {
        // We're done
        $('#folderData').listview('refresh');
    }

}
```

But really you should not be creating lots of tables with the same structure and different names, you should have one table with all the data connected by a relationship, then you can use my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757321/3408).

Comment: can you suggest how to make one table with all data connected with by relation ship.Take  above example..?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to do this synchronously, and it's probably not a good idea to try.

In this case, you can probably get the value you are after using a subquery, something like:

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CaseTableDetail WHERE CaseTableDetail.CaseID = CaseTable.id)
        AS CaseCount
FROM CaseTable;
```

(this is just a guess as you haven't specified your full table structure for the CaseName table)

Edit:

For the above to work, you will need a proper relational structure, rather than be adding tables dynamically. You should have only 2 tables, I'm going to call them CaseTable and CaseDetailTable.

CaseTable is exactly what you already have.

CaseDetailTable is similar to the Test and Test2 tables above, but has an extra field, CaseID
Now I have two more table in DB
Test , Test2..

```
   ID    CaseID      DocumentName    Date        Notes
    1         1      ppp             7/33        asdhdfkdshf
    2         1      asdjhad         9/44        dfjasgfsjfj
    3         2      sad              7/4        asdhdfkdshf
    4         2      assd            3/44        hhhhhh
    5         2      asd             2/22        adgjad
```

So the CaseID field is a pointer to the entry in the CaseTable that each row is part of. Using WHERE, JOIN and subqueries like the one I used above, you will be able to access all the data much more efficiently. You can tell SQLite that this is what you are doing by using the REFERENCES keyword. This will tell the database to create indexes to make looking up CaseDetails faster, and it will make sure that you cannot add any rows to CaseDetailTable unless you have a corresponding entry in CaseTable.

You can create the CaseDetailTable as follows:

```
   CREATE TABLE CaseDetailTable (
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
       CaseID INTEGER REFERENCES CaseTable (ID),
       Notes  TEXT unique NOT NULL,
       DocumentName INTEGER,
       Date TEXT NOT NULL
   );
```

Comment: I will explain full structure...!!

Comment: any idea of ths question

Answer (score 0):

I do like this ..!!It is working..Thank for help

```
function getallTableData(tx) {
     // tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS a");

   tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}




function querySuccess(tx, result) {


    var len = result.rows.length;
    var countDoument=0
    $('#folderData').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

         alert(i)

         test1=result.rows.item(i).CaseName;


     Test1(test1, function(i) {
      return function(result_count) {
        countDoument = result_count; // here it count value 
        alert(result_count + "result_count") //alert is correct count value
        alert(i + "i"); 

        $('#folderData').append(
            '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + result.rows.item(i).id + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseName + countDoument + '</h2>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).TextArea + '</p>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseDate + '</p>' +'<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span>'+  '</a>' +
            '<span class="ctrl togg"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" ><button class="edit button_design">Edit</button><button class="del button_design">Delete</button></fieldset><span>' + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span>'+ '</li>'
        );
           $('#folderData').listview('refresh');

      };

    }(i));





}


}

function Test1(test, callBack){
    var x;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
            $yoursql = 'SELECT * FROM  "'+test+'" ';
            tx.executeSql($yoursql, [], function (tx, results) {
                x = results.rows.length  + "TableName" + test;
                callBack(x);                
            });
    });

}
```