# (getting error cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' )?

Tags: jquery, sql, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

[How can I fetch data synchronously from cordova-sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752946/need-example-of-synchronous-data-fetch-from-database-in-sqlite/17757321?noredirect=1#17757321)
I am solving this question .I raised lot of question in my mind .Why sqlite not serialization pattern.Mean:why it is not execute line by line..?

I solve like that..

```
var db = "";
//will create database Dummy_DB or open it

//function will be called when device ready
var caseNames=new Array();
function onDeviceReady() {


    db = window.openDatabase("Casepad", "1.0", "Casepad", 200000);
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("isAddSomeData") == "yes") {

        db.transaction(getallTableData, errorCB);

        /*db.transaction(function (tx) {

 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM a', [],
   // tx.executeSql('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM  b)', [],
              function(tx, results) {
               t=results.rows.length;
               alert(t)
});
    });*/

    }    
}

function insertData() {
    db.transaction(createTable, errorCB, afterSuccessTableCreation);
}

//create table and insert some record
function createTable(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaseTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, CaseName  VARCHAR(100) unique NOT NULL ,CaseDate INTEGER ,TextArea VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL)');

    tx.executeSql('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO CaseTable(CaseName,CaseDate,TextArea) VALUES ("' + $('.caseName_h').val() + '", "' + $('.caseDate_h').val() + '","' + $('.caseTextArea_h').val() + '")');


}
//function will be called when an error occurred
function errorCB(err) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}

//function will be called when process succeed
function afterSuccessTableCreation() {
    console.log("success!");
    db.transaction(getallTableData, errorCB);
}



//select all from SoccerPlayer
function getallTableData(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CaseTable', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}


/*function querySuccess(){
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    alert(result.rows.item(0).CaseName)
        db.transaction(function (tx) {

 tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM "'+result.rows.item(0).CaseName+'"', [],
   // tx.executeSql('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM  b)', [],
              function(tx, results) {
               t=results.rows.length;
               alert(t)
});
    });

}

}*/
function querySuccess(tx, result) {

    var len = result.rows.length;
    $('#folderData').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    test=result.rows.item(i).CaseName;
    if(test=="a"){

    var t=Test(test);
     alert("yes" +t)
}


        $('#folderData').append(
                '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + result.rows.item(i).id + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseName + '</h2>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).TextArea + '</p>' + '<p>' + result.rows.item(i).CaseDate + '</p>' + '</a>' + 
                 '<span class="ctrl togg"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" ><button class="edit button_design">Edit</button><button class="del button_design">Delete</button></fieldset><span>'+'</li>'
                );
    }
    $('#folderData').listview('refresh');

}

function Test(test){
alert(test)
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
            $yoursql = 'SELECT * FROM  "'+test+'"';
            tx.executeSql($yoursql, [], function (tx, results) {
                return results.rows.length+"TableName"+test;

            });
});

}
```

After Run I will get first **yesundefined**  then , table name .in console i get this error

**Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'**

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$('#folderData').listview('refresh');
```

to this:

```
$('#folderData').listview().listview('refresh');
```

In some cases a listview must be initialized with **`listview()`** before it can be refreshed with **`listview('refresh')`**.

Comment: hi @gajotres please look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707575/unexpected-behaviour-shown-while-opening-the-pop-up-screen-in-ipad-usingjquery-m

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ID').trigger('create');
```

then

```
$('#ID').append(APPEND_CONTENT).listview('refresh');
```