# How to count the number of elements in table sqlite phonegap

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova

can you please tell me how to count the `number` of elements in a table in `sqlite`.It is not giving correct `result`.

```
function Test(test){
alert(test)
var x;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
            $yoursql = 'SELECT * FROM  "'+test+'"';
            tx.executeSql($yoursql, [], function (tx, results) {
                alert(results.rows.length+ "rows")
                x= results.rows.length+"TableName"+test;

            });
            return x;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
function Test(test){
    alert(test)
    var x;
    db.readTransaction(function (t) {
        t.executeSql('SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM ' + test, [], function (t, r) {
            alert(r.rows[0].c + "rows")
            x= r.rows[0].c+"TableName"+test;
        });
    });
    return x
}
```

I replaced `db.transaction` with `db.readTransaction`, added a `COUNT(*) AS c` instead of `*` and so I replaced `results.rows.length` with `r.rows[0].c`. For more information, you can have a look to the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/).

Comment: can you help in this question also..!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752946/need-example-of-synchronous-data-fetch-from-database-in-sqlite

Comment: I don't understand. I answered to your question... Why also ?

Comment: Because i have one more problem biggest problem in this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752946/need-example-of-synchronous-data-fetch-from-database-in-sqlite.same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752946/need-example-of-synchronous-data-fetch-from-database-in-sqlite

Comment: check again..!! i have same problem in this question

Comment: Thanks man..!! this is more tougher question but having same concept

Comment: can we add check functionality if "test" not exist in db? then return 0.?

Comment: Yes you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists But why do you unvalidate my answer ?

Comment: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='test' like this ?

Comment: Ok. I will try to answer to your ask too.

Comment: No no. The response under. This : create table if not exists TableName (col1 typ1, ..., colN typN)

Comment: i don't want to create i want to return zero if table not exist..in same question

Comment: Ok. And what is it happened if you select rows in table which doesn't exist ?

Comment: you are tell about second question ..?If you have any answer post there.I am asking about this question that if you have "test" undefined then what will happen we need to check this..

Comment: if test is undefined i need to return zero

Comment: So, you can check if it returns undefined, and that is it you return 0.

Comment: please answer my second question..!! that was critical question

Answer (score 3):

```
var countSql = "SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM users";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, countSql, []).then(function (res) {
    console.log("count : " + res.rows.item(0).cnt);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use callBack function also..

```
function Test(test, callBack){
    var x;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
            $yoursql = 'SELECT * FROM  "'+test+'" ';
            tx.executeSql($yoursql, [], function (tx, results) {
                x = results.rows.length  + "TableName" + test;
                callBack(x);                
            });
    });

}
```

Call function like this..

```
Test('users',function(result_count){
  alert(result_count);
});
```

Comment: users is table name.?  result_count number of element ?

Comment: is this apply on this question also .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752946/need-example-of-synchronous-data-fetch-from-database-in-sqlite

Comment: can we add check functionality if "test" not exist in db? then return 0.?

Comment: i don't do that i think by mistake it happen sorry ..where your answer gone..:(please paste again..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762679/why-the-value-i-increase-by-own-i-this-loop-while-fetching-the-data-from-sqlite

Comment: do you have any idea of this question?

Answer (score 0):

May use this

```
var dBase = null;
function devicereadyFun(){
    dBase = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
        name: 'test.db',
        location: 'default'
    });
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', devicereadyFun, false);

function Test(test){
    dBase.executeSql("select count(*) as cut from "+test, [], function(rsp){
        alert('Rows count in '+test+': '+rsp.rows.item(0).cut);
    });
}
```